# Conditionally set background color in React component with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to use a hex color code passed through props to set the background color of a div. These are one-off colors that are generated dynamically, so cannot be added as a theme extension in `tailwind.config`.

I thought a template literal would be the best way to achieve this, but have not been able to get this to work with arbitrary color values in Tailwind CSS.

```
interface Props {
  color: string;
}

const ColorSwatch = ({ color }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 p-2">
      <div
        className={`h-20 w-20 border border-gray-400 shadow-md bg-[${color}]`}
      ></div>
      <p className="text-center">{color}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColorSwatch;
```

Pasting the hex color code directly into the className list produces expected results, but trying to use the prop value in a template literal results in a transparent background (no background effect applied).

Looking for advice on how to correct this or different approaches to dynamically setting background color with a hex code passed through props.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tailwind requires the color to be hardcoded into the `className` prop as it cannot compute arbitrary styles from dynamic `className` values.

Your best bet would be to set the background color using the `style` prop as shown below;

```
interface Props {
  color: string;
}

const ColorSwatch = ({ color }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1 p-2">
      <div
        className="h-20 w-20 border border-gray-400 shadow-md"
        style={{backgroundColor: color}}
      ></div>
      <p className="text-center">{color}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColorSwatch;
```

You can look [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) and [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth) to read more on how Tailwind generates arbitrary styles.

Answer (score 1):

From [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> Dynamic class names
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names
> together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate
> the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don't construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do
> not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
>
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```
>
> **Always map props to static class names**
>
> ```
> function Button({ color, children }) {   const colorVariants = {
>     blue: 'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-500',
>     red: 'bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-500',   }
>
>   return (
>     <button className={`${colorVariants[color]} ...`}>
>       {children}
>     </button>   ) }
> ```